# How to base64 encode a Python script

Tags: python, base64

I'm trying to base64 encode a python file then insert it into a txt file I've tried the following code:

import base64

```
file = open('Python.py', 'r')
txt = open('New.txt', 'wb')
encoded = base64.b64encode(file).read()
txt.write(encoded)
txt.writelines(lines)
file.close()
txt.close()
```

The error returned is TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'

Comment: To run the script it obviously has to be valid python code. So the only way you can run it is to decrypt it first.

Comment: I have decrypted it but the first line it outputs is "import TKinter *\n" and nothing there out

Comment: Why are you encoding the source file line by line? That makes it painful (if not downright impossible) to decode it correctly. You should encode the whole thing in one go.

Comment: and, besides, since you're writing text (which b64-encoded data _is_), you don't need to open the second file in binary mode - ``'w'`` should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a short Python 3 program that encodes any binary file to Base64.

#### base64encode.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import base64
import sys

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print('Encode a file with Base64\nUsage:\n%s filename' % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit()

    fname = sys.argv[1]
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()

    with open(fname + 'b64', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(base64.encodebytes(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's what it produces when fed its own source code (which was saved as UTF-8).

#### base64encode.pyb64

```
IyEvdXNyL2Jpbi9lbnYgcHl0aG9uMwoKaW1wb3J0IGJhc2U2NAppbXBvcnQgc3lzCgpkZWYgbWFp
bigpOgogICAgaWYgbGVuKHN5cy5hcmd2KSAhPSAyOgogICAgICAgIHByaW50KCdFbmNvZGUgYSBm
aWxlIHdpdGggQmFzZTY0XG5Vc2FnZTpcbiVzIGZpbGVuYW1lJyAlIHN5cy5hcmd2WzBdKQogICAg
ICAgIHN5cy5leGl0KCkKCiAgICBmbmFtZSA9IHN5cy5hcmd2WzFdCiAgICB3aXRoIG9wZW4oZm5h
bWUsICdyYicpIGFzIGY6CiAgICAgICAgZGF0YSA9IGYucmVhZCgpCgogICAgd2l0aCBvcGVuKGZu
YW1lICsgJ2I2NCcsICd3YicpIGFzIGY6CiAgICAgICAgZi53cml0ZShiYXNlNjQuZW5jb2RlYnl0
ZXMoZGF0YSkpCgppZiBfX25hbWVfXyA9PSAnX19tYWluX18nOgogICAgbWFpbigpCg==
```

And here's some code that reverses the process

```
import base64

with open('base64encode.pyb64', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
with open('newfile', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(base64.decodebytes(data))
```

The resulting `newfile` is identical to `base64encode.py`